# Client Generated doesn't provide information about knowntype with third-party

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, inheritance, known-types

I've got some problems with my Service, about the KnownType and inheritance. I've read almost all the similar question, but i still haven't found a solution. I'll try to explain:

This is my interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "MyNameSpace.Components.Web")]    
public interface ITransactionsService
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "Put")]        
    void Put(WebTransactionItem wtransactionItem);
}
```

this is my DataContract :

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "MyNameSpace.Components.Web")]
public class WebTransactionItem
{        
    [DataMember]
    public TransactionItem items { get; set; }

    [DataMember]        
    public TransactionItem[] TransactionItemList { get; set; }        
}
```

*TransactionItem* is an abstract class provided in an (another) assembly.

The same assembly is used in the client project, so i've the same type referenced in both client and server.
On the client side, after some operations(read a file etc.etc.), i have an array of objects that inherits from *TransactionItem*, says:

```
transItems[0] => TransactionHeaderObject
transItems[1] => TransactionTrailerObject
```

In the Service Web.config i've added

```
<dataContractSerializer>
  <declaredTypes>        
    <add type="Namespace.TransactionItem, Assemblyname, Version=1.4.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <knownType type="Namespace.TransactionHeader, Assemblyname, Version=1.4.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <knownType type="Namespace.TransactionTrailer, Assemblyname, Version=1.4.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    </add>
  </declaredTypes>
</dataContractSerializer>
```

of course i could have used the *KnownTypeAttribute* on the [Datacontract] decorator.
If in the *Configure Service Reference* (in the client project Service reference) i check(is checked by default) the *Reuse types in referenced assemblies* flag, i'm able to write in my code :

```
MyNameSpace.Components.Web.WebTransactionItem wtItem = 
   new MyNameSpace.Components.Web.WebTransactionItem(){ 
       TransactionItemList = transItems}
```

and i'm able to call the Service without problems. So what is the question?
 The question is that if i remove the

```
[DataMember]
public TransactionItem items { get; set; }
```

property(i don't want a client to use an abstract class) from the DataContract the Service goes in exception:

*There was an error while trying to serialize parameter  MyNameSpace.Components.Web:wtransactionItem. Innerexception Message :
Type 'Assemblyname.TransactionHeader' with contract name 'TransactionHeader:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Assemblyname' is not expected.*

Now, as far i've understood, this happens when i don't specify the type *TransactionHeader* (that inherits TransactionItem) in the Service, but i do(see the Web.Config service's file, also i've tried with knowntypeAttribute)!!
Also i've noticed that in the *Reference.cs* class automatically generated in the client project, in the first case (when i leave the

```
[DataMember]
public TransactionItem items { get; set; }
```

property)

Is coded:

```
[KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(Assemblyname.TransactionHeader))]

[KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(Assemblyname.TransactionTrailer))]
```

above the generated partial class. That permits the serialization of the inherited classes, but if i remove the property in the Service, the partial class (inside the Reference.cs) doesn't have it anymore, that's why the Service throws that exception. It's like it misses a reference to the abstract class *TransactionItem* even if i've specified it in the Web.config file(and also via the KnownTypeAttribute.). How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the "ServiceKnownTypeAttribute" ?
To serialize or deserialize a type, WCF needs to know the concrete base class through this attribute or through the service contract itself.
When you have an interface (or probably also an abstract class) in your service contract, the serializer misses something when only using the KnownTypeAttribute.
As you want to register types from another assembly, you probaly have to provide a method that returns a list of known types and register this method:

```
 [ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(Helper))]
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately i've also tried the _ServiceKnownType_ Decorator both specifying all the types involved(about 20 types), and as you've suggested, but the result is the same. I think it's as you say : the serializer misses something with the abstract class. Also i've tried not to use the same assembly (the one which include the types) in the client generation : the trick seems to work, but i have to use some reflection tricks since the types generated are, obviously, not the same (even if  they actually are ;) ).